# How do you convert a java LWJGL game into javascript/web assembly?

Tags: javascript, java, 3d, lwjgl, webassembly

I want to convert a 3D LWJGL game into javascript/web assembly to use on a website. How can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK LWJGL is based on native libraries and OpenGL bindings. It is not possible to transpile those native parts to WebAssembly. However, if you have a plain Java application without native parts, a good starting point might by http://teavm.org/ or Bytecoder https://github.com/mirkosertic/Bytecoder.

Disclaimer: I am the author of Bytecoder.